# JavaScript (Ajax) refresh div if off screen

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, draggable

I use the awesome plugin [Pep.js](http://pep.briangonzalez.org/) to drag things around.

I have 3 draggable cards and when it go off screen, it need to refresh itself automatically, so it's on the begin place again. Is this possible with JavaScript or Ajax?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This schould solve your problem:
http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-test-if-element-is-in-viewport-visible-on-screen

The script checks if an element is in viewport.

Comment: Thanks, but it need to refresh the div when I swipe it off screen. So I have a div and I hold it and when I swipe it, it refreshes itself automatically.